# Trello search for not closed cards

Tags: trello

I need to search through non-closed cards on board.

I tried to search with this params:

```
{
'query': 'description:' + query,
'idBoards': [board_id],
'modelTypes': ['cards'],
'card_fields': ['closed']
}
```

But i get list of cards that include closed cards also.

How could i search within not-closed cards only?